# Upgraded ubuntu to 16.04 Libreoffice shows non printable characters

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS. I had manually installed LibreOffice 5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 and there was no problem. As part of the upgrade process LibreOffice 5.1.4.2 was re-installed automatically. Now when I see file properties, it displays non printable characters in parts of the General tab of Properties. This is also happening in tabs of Tools -> Customize and messages displayed by Librecalc. The language settings are set to English. How can this be rectified.

[image: Libre Calc screenshot of Properties]

Comment: Possibly related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1575000?

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter the same issue when I install Ubuntu 16.04 and use LibreOffice recently.

A temporary workaround is that you can try to click on the non printable characters, sometimes it will bring back the printable characters. However, it is not working for all these strange characters.

[image: LibreOffice non printable characters]

Comment: @neelanshu I haven't observed this issue recently in LibreOffice. It seems this issue has been solved. Please make sure your Ubuntu is up-to-date.